# Implement Google Maps-like image dragging functionality?

Tags: user-interface, visualization

I have a graph with 1000+ nodes that is fairly sparse. I would like to create a visualization of this graph, and let users drag around it, the same way that users can drag the image of Google or Bing maps around.

Is there any service/toolkit/technology that exists to allow me to do this easily? Javascript? Silverlight? Flash/Flex?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript

1. [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/)
2. [Javascript Infovis Toolkit](http://thejit.org/)

Flash:

1. [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/)